# VirtualHost: Deactivate catch all for SSL (443)

Tags: apache, ssl, debian, virtualhost, server

I created a SSL VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName cloud.url.com
    ServerAlias www.url.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/owncloud.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/owncloud.key
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is that every SSL connection now is going to `/var/www/owncloud`

For instance https://url.com is going to `/var/www/owncloud` instead of `/var/www/`

How can I only set the VirtualHost for `cloud.url.com` and the other domains "ignore the ssl" - so they stay in there directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, your virtualhost says www.url.com and cloud.url.com goes to /var/www/owncloud. I think you don't want www.url.go to points to your owncloud. So, just remove serverAlias :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName cloud.url.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/owncloud.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/owncloud.key
</VirtualHost>
```

I think you haven't set any virtualhost listening to url.com on port 443. That's why, apache redirect it to an url configured with https.
if you don't want ssl on url.com, you can just do this :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName url.com
  Redirect 301 / http://url.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, put this in one file together:

```
     <VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName cloud.domain.com
       ServerAlias www.cloud.domain.com
       DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud
       <Directory /var/www/owncloud/>
         Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
       </Directory>
       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/owncloud.crt
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/owncloud.key
     </VirtualHost>

     <VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName domain.com
       ServerAlias *.domain.com
       Redirect 301 / http://domain.com
     </VirtualHost>
```

Thank you!